# Creating Folder structure in Content section in umbraco 4.11

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

I dont know where is the right place to write this question but asking here..

Currently im having my Content section as below:

Content->index

Content->Our Products -> Our product1, Our Product 2

Content -> Out top Products->Our top product1, Our top product2

so all starts from Content root

i want this to be changed to following structure:

Content->Pharmacy->Our Products......

Content->Pharmacy-> Our Top PRodoucts

i want all URL having structure as below:

http://domain.com/Pharmacy/Products1

but i dont know how to do that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve the url structure that you want, your node structure will need to be like this:

- Content

  - Home

    - Pharmacy

      - Our Products

        - Our Product 1
        - Our Product 2
      - Our Top Products

        - Our Top Product 1
        - Our Top Product 2

Everything should live under Home, which is considered the root of the site.